# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList gradle:2.1.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

So, I have a project with a private library. My lib has some classes that I want use on my project, but when I execute the app and try to access the class it occurs that exception:

> Process: chat.omni.loja, PID: 32615
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/omnichat/chat_library/_util/GaleryUtils;
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.omnichat.chat_library._util.GaleryUtils" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/chat.omni.loja/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9_c46d74b6abb1c51e69093e6cb8bf4a5f5e9b987f-classes.dex", dex file
>
> ...
>
> "/data/data/chat.omni.loja/files/instant-run/dex/slice-dependencies_f7fd1358be3ac9af2f69ac6f15447a76a8be062c-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

This is my library build gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  ext { supportLibVersion = '23.+' }

  //CircleImageView Library
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
  // SMACK Library
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0-alpha3'
  compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0-alpha3'
  //Glide Library
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
  //SectionCursorAdapter Library
  compile 'com.twotoasters.SectionCursorAdapter:library:1.0.+'
  //Android Annotations Library
  compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
  //Android Annotations apt
  apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
}
```

And my app build gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

   ext { supportLibVersion = '23.+' }
   //Library dependency
   compile(project(':chat-library')) {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7';
       exclude group: 'org.androidannotations', module: "androidannotations:$AAVersion";
       exclude group: 'org.androidannotations', module: "androidannotations-api:$AAVersion";
   }

   //Supports Library
   compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
   compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
   compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
   compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
   // Crashlytics Kit
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
       transitive = true
   }
   //Android Annotations Library
   apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
   compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
   //Parser Library
   compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
   compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
   compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
   //Stetho Library
   compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'
   //Material SearchView Library
   compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.+'
   //CropImage Library
   compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

My configurations are:

- Android Studio 2.1 Preview 1
- Android Gradle Plugin 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'
- Build Tools Version 23.0.2
- Gradle Version 2.10

I googled this problem for 2 long days and I tried everything that I found on SO. so MAYBE it could be a bug on new gradle version but I cant affirm that. Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/building/multidex.html, and in gradle-wrapper file, try distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip. Probably you have very dependencies and need multidex depencie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Victor Gomes! Your tip was great.. I just updated to **gradle-2.11** and it worked again!